# Adding space between two buttons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using haml.erb file. I would like to add space between two buttons in UI. Now the two buttons are appearing one after one without space. How can i do?

```
 = link_to :back, :class => "btn btn-success", :href => '/pt_setup' do
    %i.icon-arrow-left.icon-white
    Back &nbsp; // does not workout
  =link_to "New Subscription", { :controller => "pt_app", :action => "new_subn"}, :class => 'btn btn-success'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add margin left on second button. you can add class on second button e.g

```
 =link_to "New Subscription", { :controller => "pt_app", :action => "new_subn"}, :class => 'btn btn-success left-margin'
```

and then you can add css in your haml file

```
:css
  .left-margin { margin-left: 2px }
```

Or you can add inline css to one of these buttons.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Bootstrap

1. Wrap your buttons in a div with class=`'col-xs-3'` (for example).
2. Add class=`"btn-block"` to your buttons.

**Note:** No need to use extra css unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Your current code puts a space behind the text 'Back', which is inside your link/button, so of course this will not have any affect on the spacing between the buttons themselves.

It has been a while since using haml but something along the lines of:

```
= link_to :back, :class => "btn btn-success", :href => '/pt_setup' do
  %i.icon-arrow-left.icon-white
  Back
&nbsp;
= link_to "New Subscription", { :controller => "pt_app", :action => "new_subn"}, :class => 'btn btn-success'
```

Should work in your case.

However, why leave layout / styling to your template at all? use CSS for organizing your layout, put a margin on the right side of .btn class elements, or add a new custom button class and add the margin to limit the scope of buttons affected if you don't want a global margin setting on all buttons.

Comment: Thank u @john hayes

Comment: @Jefferson no problem, i see you are using bootstrap, if you are using bootstrap 4, you can use the .ml-1 or .mr-1 classes already provided to add margins to your elements without having to write any css yourself.

Comment: Thank u again @john hayes –

Comment: @Jefferson : you can add `btn-block` class in your links

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 = link_to :back, :class => "btn btn-success", :href => '/pt_setup' do
    %i.icon-arrow-left.icon-white
    Back &nbsp; // does not workout
  =link_to "New Subscription", { :controller => "pt_app", :action => "new_subn"}, :class => 'btn btn-success', :style => 'margin-left:10px;'
```

Comment: @Jefferson, I've added margin for second button.

Comment: @jefferson There is inline css on link_to

Comment: @Sajin - Thank u bro

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a css for spacing. You can add ">" at the end of your brackets for space before and "<" for space after.

Example:

```
%form
  %input{name: "search", placeholder: "Text Here", type: "text"}
  %button{type: "submit"}>
    %i.fa.fa-search
```

Will space before the button, separating it from the input text box

Or Equivalently:

```
%form
  %input{name: "search", placeholder: "Text Here", type: "text"}<
  %button{type: "submit"}
    %i.fa.fa-search
```

Will space after the input box